# This view is not constrained vertically. At runtime it will jump to the left unless you add a vertical constraint

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-edittext, layout-editor

[image]New Layout editor in Android Studio 2.2 keeps showing this error on views like EditText and Buttons. kindly help.Also, any links that help in onboarding with the new constraint layout would be appreciated.

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.set.email.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="To:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="7dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/textTo"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/editTo"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="94dp"
        android:id="@+id/editSubject"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="273dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="179dp"
        android:id="@+id/editMessage"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/activity_main"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="50"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="140dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="454dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editMessage"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="0"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What error? Please describe your actual problem. This is not nearly enough detail.

Comment: can you share your xml code??

Comment: When finished laying out constraint layout, click the button to add all missing constraints automatically.

Comment: button? you mean the red lint bulb? its not showing any options to add missing constraints automatically.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Constraint layout aims at reducing layout hierarchies and improves performance of layouts(technically, you don't have to make changes for different screen sizes,No overlapping, works like charm on a mobile as well as a tab with the same constraints).Here's how you get rid of the above error when you're using the new layout editor.

[image]

Click on the small circle and drag it to the left until the circle turns green,to add a left constraint(give a number, say x dp. Repeat it with the other sides and leave the bottom constraint blank if you have another view below it. 
[image]

Edit: According to the developers site, Instead of adding constraints to every view as you place them in the layout, you can move each view into the positions you desire, and then click Infer Constraints to automatically create constraints. more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

Comment: I have just addded imageview in contraint layout but is not showing when I run app. can you please help me ?

Answer (score 118):

From Android Studio v3 and up, Infer Constraint was removed from the dropdown.

Use the **magic wand icon** in the toolbar menu above the design preview; there is the "**Infer Constraints**" button. Click on this button, this will automatically add some lines in the text field and the red line will be removed.

[image]

Comment: In my case, it only add an ignore constraint but it doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: this solution is easier than the top one. But only works for AS v3 and later.

Answer (score 64):

Just copy this code to all components that you will drag.

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

example:

```
<TextView
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:text="To:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="7dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/textTo"/>
```

Comment: But why? Can you explain its details?

Answer (score 32):

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

This help me a lot

Answer (score 24):

Go to the Design, right click on your Widget, 
Constraint Layout >> Infer Constraints. You can observe that some code has been automatically added to your Text.

Comment: Yes the infer constraints uses the defaults values specified in the activity.xml file

Answer (score 5):

```
Follow these steps:
Right click on designing part > Constraint Layout > Infer Constraints
```

Answer (score 5):

If Inferring the `Constraints` still gives you the error, just use this code:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to drag the `EditText` from the edge of the layout and not just the other widget. You can also add constraints by just dragging the constraint point that surrounds the widget to the edge of the screen to add constraints as specified.

The modified code will look something similar to this:

```
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/router_text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.29"
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the XML layout Text where the widget (button or other View) indicates error, focus the cursor there and press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> and select missing constraints attributes.

Comment: It also gives warning message that Hardcoded string "TextView", should use @string resource

Answer (score 1):

for example I have this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

use RelativeLayout layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply switch to the Design View, and locate the concerned widget. Grab the one of the dots on the boundary of the widget and join it to an appropriate edge of the screen (or to a dot on some other widget).

For instance, if the widget is a toolbar, just grab the top-most dot and join it to the top-most edge of the phone screen as shown in the image.

[image: Design View]

Answer (score 0):

## Steps to add 4 screen constraints margins snippet to android studio IDE:

1. Go to `File -> Settings -> search bar` and search for `live templates`
2. select `AndroidXML` and click the add button `+` and select `Live Template` like shown in screenshot:
   [image]
3. fill abbreviation of your choosing (I used `ccc`), click `define` and choose `XML Attribute` and add the template code:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

screenshot:
[image]
4. click OK and you're done, when you add new component just type your abbreviation and press Enter and the constraints will be all set:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -6):

You have to change `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` to `RelativeLayout`.