# GUI elements not displaying properly

Tags: android, user-interface

I was following along some Android tutorial on Youtube when I encountered the following problem:
(left the designer, right the emulator)
[image]

I tried searching on google, but can't seem to find the right link.
Does anyone have any idea what is going on? I tried deleting and placing new elements, but the same problem keeps occurring.

[Edit]
XML code which I didn't change. This was created with a new project.
[image]
All elements in the picture were dragged and dropped. No code was changed.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context="com.example.todor.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="159dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="235dp"
        tools:text="@string/loginbutton" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
        tools:text="@string/logintext"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="126dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:width="300dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/emailhint"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="42dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:width="300dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/passowrdhint"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="42dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLay
```

out>

Comment: [Study layouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: @ilan Todorovic what's your issue? where is your XML ? what kind of help you need from us?

Comment: @Charuක The left side of the image is the order of the elements I placed using the Designer and the right side is what is displayed in the emulator. I didn't mess with the code. I have no idea why this happened.

Comment: how can we help if you do not post the xml check your **setContentView** and which XML is linked to your Activity, It seems you have wrong XML for  your Activity

Comment: @Milan Todorovic what is your XML name again? uninstall and try or did you check with a real device ?

Comment: @Charuක You can see it in the second screenshot (the second tab which is open). It's the default name activity_main.

Comment: @Milan Todorovic post your activity_main.xml in your question

Comment: @tools:text insted of `tools:text` use `android:text` `tools:text` is only to check the data in the design , and you view is not properly positioned! so it will jump to 0,0 , your view is only created for design view not for runtime

Comment: @Charuක Can you tell my why it is not positioned? Shouldn't the Designer do it automatically based on the position I dragged the element to? It even let's me center the damn elements...

Comment: @Milan Todorovic Its  because  you are using ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tips for you !

Read about **[Tools Attributes Reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html)**

Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools namespace that **enable design-time features** (such as which layout to show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking mode to apply to your XML resources). When you build your app, the build tools remove these attributes so there is **no effect** on your APK size or runtime behavior.

You need to understand the difference of below attributes!

```
tools:text="loginbutton"
android:text="loginbutton"
```

Your views are not constrained they have **only design time position**!
Go to the design, drag the corners until the circle turns green and then give the constraint.Here is an extra guidance from [linkOne](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/starting-out-with-constraint-layout-and-android-studios-visual-editor) [LinkTwo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859613/this-view-is-not-constrained-vertically-at-runtime-it-will-jump-to-the-left-unl) related with `ConstraintLayout`

If you mess it up big-time you can replace `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` with `LinearLayout` but that's not the solution it's another way instead!