# Constraint Layout not visible on the Layout file...And getting the error while inflating any view on it

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I am using the constraint layout (`android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`) as the main layout in my XML file. As we get the two View of layout(One is for User View And Second is for the drag and drop the view and provide the relation between them) .But i am getting only one window which is totally blank and look alike below :-[image]

And getting this error while using any view in my layout.Please check below image for it

[image]

My layout file is as below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_shot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried the below solution on SO, but it is not working for me,Please check the link , which i have searched

[1. First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817537/this-view-is-not-constrained) 
[2. Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859613/this-view-is-not-constrained-vertically-at-runtime-it-will-jump-to-the-left-unl) 
[3. Third Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518745/evenly-spacing-views-using-constraintlayout)

Please help me to short out from this problem.Thanks

Comment: That display is what you will see if the `ConstraintLayout` class cannot be found. Please share what version of Android Studio you are using and your gradle scripts.

Comment: Still the blank screen appear on the layout preview :(  ..Thanks for input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you don't give any `constraint` for `ImageView`. When you give `constraint` to `ImageView` then that warning will be removed.

Like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_shot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

set your gradle like below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // for Databinding

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hellokotlin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    android {
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.1'       // for Databinding
}
```

Support lib version and buildToolsVersion

```
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hellokotlin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to start with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If preview is not showing try to change selected device or check imlemented library in gradle `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`

Comment: I have already used the 'implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'' but still the same problem is here..Thanks for input

Comment: Still the blank screen appear on the layout preview :(

Comment: Thanks for input..+1 for ur effort

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, your layout is not Constraint so it's stuck in the left top corner. In order to add constraints using the design view change the absolute values first, e.g. :

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp"
```

and than constraint your layout as you wish. In the example below it's in the centre.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_shot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for input..Still the blank screen appear on the layout preview :(

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this attribute  `tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" from xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Clean Project

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue as I was new to Constraint layout.
 
Adding `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'` 
in **build.gradle (module)** file resolve my issue.

Comment: Thanks for the input +1 for the effort