# Android Studio 3 constraint layout editor Issue

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 with the latest update on macOS recently the constraint layout editor stopped working. It's working when i run on the code on emulator/device but for the design and preview tabs it doesn't show up.
[image: Constraint layout editor problem]
I'm using constraint layout 1.0.2 i tried the other versions as well not working.

i have tried support library 26, 26-beta1 and 26-beta2 no good there as well.

Comment: Android Studio 3.0 is still in the preview phase and thus not considered stable. Please, use the stable version 2.3.3

Comment: clear and rebuild project or just close it and reopen

Comment: tried all of those, clear, rebuild, invalidate, restart everything.    Also i'm using kotlin to development thats why i'm using Android Studio 3.0

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. Rendering fails with "Failed to instantiate one or more classes. Rendering failed with a know bug." Nothing I have tried clears this error. Since it seems to be a known defect, I assume that the fix is coming down the pike. In the meantime, you might try to build the layout in a stable version of Studio and copy it over. It's not ideal, but it will enable you to update your layout using the design tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have face same issue while i update my `Android Studio`. it's because of your `support library` latest version.
see this : [See Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45094927/1343788)

In this Main thing you have to check `gradle` file.

In sort you have to down support lib version because 26 version is still in beta phase

`compile com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'`

Comment: yes thx, version 26 is not stable i guess, changing it to 25.4 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change the theme to Material will solve the issue.
By default it will be AppTheme