# Android Studio 3 beta 2, support library 26.0.1 and font preview in layout editor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

Using Android Studio 3 beta 2, just create a new empty project with empty activity and follow the instructions on [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/fonts-in-xml.html). I cannot see the custom font in editor preview and the TextView preview uses Roboto. 
As you imagine new projects are created using android support library 26.0.1. 
If I change the support library version to 26.0.0-beta1, all works correctly and the preview is displayed using the custom font.

Does anyone experience the same problem and if you already fix this, how do you fix?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45115111/1343788