# Android Studio 3 - Constraint layout editor is not working

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I recently installed android studio 3 but The constraint layout shows a grey window..I tried everything but I couldn't fix the the problem

Thanks in advance for any help provided:

[image]

[image]

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"; 
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context="com.example.chihaoui.myapplication.MainActivi‌​ty"> 
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Show us the xml code

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.chihaoui.myapplication.MainActivity">

   

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Did you try to run the app? Is it running?

Comment: The app did not work on my phone but I didn't try the emulator

Comment: "did not work" - Why exactly? Try the emulator. I suspect if there is no error and app runs fine, then the problem has to do with the design editor

Comment: @maxtaylor post your logcat

Comment: @maxtaylor : Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45115111/1343788

Answer (score 17):

I just helped make the project and earned

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zt7D.png)

Comment: This is so weird, but Build -> Make project, made the layout editor to work.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. My case is resolved by adding the following lines on app/build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0') {
    force = true
}
```

Note the `force = true` part.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the AndroidX Support Library instead of v7. Source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#v7

Answer (score 2):

in build.gradle, just change:

```
androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3
```

to

```
androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4
```

Comment: this worked for me, seems like 2.1.3 is broken with compiled 31 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Did you sync your project,I see that yellow message in gradle file if you didn't sync project it wouldn't work

Comment: can u put in your design editor api version to smaller one and tell me is that fix issue

Comment: The funny thing that there is no error but when i run the app a pop up window appear " Unfortunalety My application has stopped '