# This view is not constrained android studio. I can not see the button even if I use Infer Constraints

Tags: java, android, android-layout

[image]

Button Doesn't appear in xml even after infer constraints is used.

[image]

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="133dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="253dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37859613/2196176).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your button is missing horizontal/vertical constraints.

Try changing your button constraint like this.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="133dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="253dp" />
```

And run your activity/fragment is a device/emulator.
Even if that doesn't show up button, there is issue rendering button over the design view of the Android Studio.
Try changing API version in editor.

Answer (score 0):

Relative positioning is one of the basic building block of creating layouts in Constraint Layout. Those constraints allow you to position a given widget relative to another one. Check out the documentation here for clear understanding :

[Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)

As for your question, Try to replace this code with your button code

```
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

it makes this button center of your activity.

read the documentation for more further detail. Link -[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)