# Why don't components show up in the Design Mode in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

The Design view in Android Studio is just blank for me. I've already followed the advice in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817537/this-view-is-not-constrained) but it doesn't work. If I right click ConstraintLayout and then Convert view it opens a window where I can click RelativeLayout but this doesn't work. Does anyone have any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem earlier this week. Everything I selected for my ConstraintLayout was invisible for a new project. I ended up selecting a different theme and it woke up after that and started showing the picked views.

Screenshot Attached:

[image]

On the right on the API number ["28" in my case]. Click on the theme [NoActionBar in my case]. I think if you try a few different themes they will eventually become visible again.