# App interface different in Android Studio and Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

An Android App development beginner here. I created a simple app which converts KMs to Miles and vice versa. Issue seems to be with the interface. The interface for activity_main.xml is as below:

[Interface on Android Studio compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyv75.jpg)

But once I emulate it on an Nexus 6 API 29 emulator, it looks weird and doesn't work properly. Tried it on a Nexus 5 emulator as well, same issue. Here's a screenshot:

[Nexus 6 API 29 Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WozNA.jpg)

Moreover, when I tried installing the apk file on my Samsung Note 8, it doesn't install, even after changing the settings and allowing unknown apps to be installed. Please help.

Comment: Code snippet of xml pls

Comment: You're not settings any constraints to your views, so it will jump to `(0,0)` at runtime. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60903555/5189517)

Answer (score 0):

Judging from first screenshot (red alert icons in "Component Tree" window) the issue is the fact that You did't constrained Your Views.
When using ConstraintLayout You can't just 'place' views in editor, they need to be constrained to something in order to be displayed in desired place.
For example: Your button with text "Convert miles to kms" should be constrained as follows:

- left to parent left
- right to parent right
- top to EditText above it or to TextView "KMs".

But other views need to also be constrained to get desired behavior.
You can read about ConstraintLayout and how to use it in this tutorial from official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout